# Mutual Authentication in JSON or AJAX only?

Tags: javascript, authentication, client-server, certificate

AFAIK we must install the client-certificate into the users browser to connect with https-sites using server-certificates to have a mutual authentication.

What about AJAX and JSON, can we connect to the server without installing the client-certificate into the browser?

In example the .cer file will be available from the webspace and NOT installed into the browser.

Comment: how will the client be able to trust that the cer is actually from your server (rather than a DNS-spoofed copy)? just get a properly signed cert

Comment: Like a man-in-the-middle-attack? Good point. Noone can say the client-certificate is downloaded by the man-in-the-middle...

Comment: your question is really confusing.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @tom what is confusing you?

Comment: You appear to be asking if you can have client authentication for "application/json" requests but not "text/html" ones... on the same server.  But that doesn't make much sense.  I'm not sure what you mean by "In example the .cer file will be available from the webspace"

Comment: @tom A webserver can contains authorized content and free content. A `.cer` file simply containing the certificate. Do you need an example?

Comment: If you can download the client certificate from the server and present it back to the server as your credentials I don't see how you can call it secure.

Comment: Maybe the client-certificate is hosted on a different server or the jsonp/ajax is located on a different server. Maybe its to choose different kind of rules/users. Maybe its only for the ssl. Maybe its only for match the contract. Maybe i like to choose the url of the certificate via javascript.